# ошибка в Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
Assets\script\Weapon.cs(75,27): error CS1061: 'Camera' does not contain a definition for 'ViewportPointToRay' and no accessible extension method 'ViewportPointToRay' accepting a first argument of type 'Camera' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Вот код:

```
using System.Collections; 

using System.Collections.Generic; 

using UnityEngine; 

using UnityEngine.UI; 
 
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour 
{ 

    public Transform FirePoint;
 
    public GameObject PulaPrefab; 

    public Camera cam; 
 
 
    //Time Shoot 

    [Header("Sensitivity Time Shoot")] 

    public float TimeShoot = 0; 

    float TimeStartShoot; 
 
    //Recherge 

    [Header("Sensitivity recherge")] 

    public float ShopVolume = 7; 

    public float StartShopVolume = 7; 
 
    public float ShopGun = 3; 
 
    //Time shoot recherge 

    [Header("Sensitivity time recherge")] 

    public float TimeShop = 0; 

    float TimeStartShop; 
 
    //TextShoot 
    public Text TextShoot; 
 
    void FixedUpdate()  
    { 
        Shoot(); 
        Recharge();   
        TextShoot.text = ShopVolume + "/" + ShopGun;  
    } 
 
    void Start()  
    { 
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>(); 
    } 
 
 
 
    //Recharge 
    void Recharge() 
    { 
        TimeStartShop += 0.02f; 
 
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && TimeStartShop >= TimeShop) 
        { 
 
            TimeStartShop = 0; 
            ShopVolume = StartShopVolume; 
            ShopGun -= 1; 
 
        } 
 
        if (ShopGun <= 0) 
        { 
            TimeStartShop = 0; 
        } 
    } 
 
    //Shoot 
    void Shoot() 
    { 
         TimeStartShoot += 0.02f; 
         
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && TimeStartShoot >= TimeShoot) 
        { 
            Ray ray = cam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0)); 
 
            RaycastHit hit; 
 
            Vector3 TP; 
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) 
            { 
                TP = hit.point; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                TP = ray.GetPoint(75); 
            } 
            Vector3 DRWS = TP - FirePoint.position; 
            Instantiate(PulaPrefab, FirePoint.position, FirePoint.rotation); 
            TimeStartShoot = 0; 
            ShopVolume -= 1; 
        } 
 
        if(ShopVolume <= 0) 
        { 
           TimeStartShoot = 0; 
        } 
     
    } 
 
     
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Версия Unity: 2022.2.12f1.

Comment: У вас точно нет в проекте скрипта с названием `Camera`? Если есть, переименуйте.

Answer (score 0):

У меня был код  код с названыем Camera, по этому, он не роботал